# focusout() or blur() not triggered with popup

Tags: jquery

I have a popup that appears when i click on a link (like a bubble field),
and i want to close it if i click outside the popup, or even inside.

I thought that focusout() would be perfect for that, but it doesn't work. I can trigger the focusin(), but not the focusout() nor blur()

HTML :

```
// This div is hidden and appears on a click on <a>

<div class="popup" id="${topo.id}">
    <div class="popuptext">
        <p class="descriptionPopup">
            <span>Description :</span>
            <br>${topo.description}<br>
            <span>Edition:</span>
            <br>${topo.dateEdition}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<li class="itemTopo" id="${topo.id}">
    <a>- <c:out value="${topo.nom}"/></a>
</li>
```

JQUERY :

```
// This function toggle the class on the link (which is ok)

var idTopo;

$(".itemTopo a").click(function () {
    idTopo = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $("#"+idTopo+" > div").toggleClass("show");
    $(this).parent().focusin();
});

// focusin is triggered (for test)
$('.itemTopo').focusin(function(){
    alert("focusin");
});


// None of these events are triggered 
// when i click anywhere on the page after the popup appeared

$('.item topo').focusout(function(){
    alert("focusout");
    $("#"+idTopo+" > div").toggleClass("show");
});

$('.itemTopo').blur(function(){
    alert("focusout");
    $("#"+idTopo+" > div").toggleClass("show");
});
```

Comment: You can actually just use the click event  to look for that. Set a click event to your popup id (or class) and then toggle your class.

Comment: $('.item topo').focusout( I see a typo there. space between class name

Comment: Focus events only work for form elements and real browser windows.

Comment: Are you using the same ID for multiple elements? `idTopo = $(this).parent().attr('id');` and `$("#"+idTopo+" > div").toggleClass("show");` makes it look like you are, also as a child if it is hidden how is it meant to trigger?

Comment: @Sachin Vishwakarma : Thanks ! But fortunately it was just while copying it in here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, but i did simpler than that.
It was indeed becaus i was not aiming at the right element with focusin().
So I put the focus and blur on the a href element, and everything works fine.

```
  <div class="popup" id="${topo.id}">
    <div class="popuptext">
        <p class="descriptionPopup">
            <span>Description :</span>
            <br>${topo.description}<br>
            <span>Edition:</span>
            <br>${topo.dateEdition}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<li class="itemTopo" id="${topo.id}"><a href="#">- <c:out value="${topo.nom}"/></a><button class="buttonReservationTopo" type="button">Réserver</button></li>
```

Jquery

```
        var idTopo;

        $(".itemTopo a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            idTopo = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $("#"+idTopo+" > div").toggleClass("show");
            $(this).focus()
        });

        $('.itemTopo a').blur(function(){
            $("#"+idTopo+" > div").toggleClass("show");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tl;dr demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/410L69a3/5/)

You can't get any focus events for normal divs. You can manually check if mouse clicked outside that popup:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // if popup is shown
    if($("#"+idTopo+"").hasClass("show")) {
        // click is not on popup or it's child node
        if(!findParentById(event.target, idTopo)) {
             // remove class show
             $("#"+idTopo+"").toggleClass("show", false);
        }
    }
});
/**
 * Checks if any of parent nodes of elm has given id
 * @param {HTMLElement} elm the starting node
 * @param {string} id
 * @param {HTMLElement} stopAtElm if this parent is reached, search stops
**/
function findParentById(elm, id, stopAtElm) {
    while (elm != null && elm != stopAtElm) {
        if (elm.nodeType == 1 && elm.id == id) {
            return elm;
        }
        elm = elm.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Focus events only work on elements that can gain focus.  It's possible to make an arbitrary element focusable with `tabindex`, but that's likely not what you want here.

An easy way to capture clicks outside the popup is to wrap it in a transparent element that covers the entire viewport — e.g. using `position: fixed` and setting all four edges to `0` — then catch clicks on that.  Even clicks inside the popup will then bubble to the wrapper and close it.  (When this isn't what you want, you can use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the bubbling.)